# Change value if referenced cell is TRUE or FALSE in VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I currently have the following VLOOKUP formula which returns "Not Installed" when the #N/A error is returned.

> =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E),[vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,FALSE)),"Not
>   Installed",VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E),[vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,FALSE))

The other two possible values in the targeted lookup cells are TRUE and FALSE. How can I make it return **INSTALLED AND ASSIGNED** when **TRUE** is found in the targeted lookup cell and **INSTALLED BUT UNASSIGNED** when **FALSE** is found in the targeted lookup cell.

Comment: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E),vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,FALSE)),"Not Installed",IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E),vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,FALSE),"INSTALLED AND ASSIGNED","INSTALLED BUT UNASSIGNED"))`? Let me know if it helps. Btw, what are you going to achive with `CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E)`? Are you using it as _array_ formula? What entire formula should do ? maybe there is a more simple way..

Comment: The document on the targeted spreadsheet has all the values with the prefix EMEA\

Comment: I see, but what is the purpose of using entire column `E` here: `CONCATENATE(,"EMEA\",E:E)`? What entire formula should do ?

Comment: Well spreadsheet1 has the hostnames down in column E as hostname but spreadsheet2 has the hostnames down in column E as EMEA\hostname. The thing is spreadsheet2 is automatically generated so I don't want to play around with it too much... plus it has 1000s of records whereas spreadsheet1 only has about 50

Comment: @simoco I'm getting an error with the code :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("EMEA\",E:E),[vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,0)),"Not Installed",IF(VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE("EMEA\",E:E),[vda.xlsx]remotepc_list!$A:$D,2,0),"INSTALLED AND ASSIGNED","INSTALLED BUT UNASSIGNED"))
```